# Is there a way to template astract methods so that a parameter to an abstract method will be typed the same as the implementing subclass?

Tags: java, parameter-passing, abstract-class

Is there a way to template astract methods so that a parameter to an abstract method will be typed the same as the implementing subclass? In other words if we have:

```
class Super {
    abstract void a_method( <Sub> param );
}

class Sub_A extends Super {
    void a_method( Sub_A param ){
        ...
    }

class Sub_B extends Super {
    void a_method( Sub_B param ){
        ...
    }
}
```

Then each subclass takes its own type as a parameter to this method. I would like to avoid using an interface or reflection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal way to do that is introduce a generic parameter:

```
abstract class Super<Sub extends Super> {
    abstract void a_method(Sub param);
}

class Sub_A extends Super<Sub_A> {
    void a_method(Sub_A param) {

    }
}

class Sub_B extends Super<Sub_B> {
    void a_method(Sub_B param) {

    }
}
```

As far as I know you cannot force the subclass to pass themselves as `T`, e.g. it would be possible to define `class Sub_C extends Super<Sub_A>`. Not sure if that is a problem.

---

Following java naming conventions it should look like:

```
abstract class Super<S extends Super> {
    abstract void aMethod(S param);
}

class SubA extends Super<SubA> {
    void aMethod(SubA param) {

    }
}

class SubB extends Super<SubB> {
    void aMethod(SubB param) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[This answer is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59127350/2733184). Just in case someone comes across this but is working with **Kotlin** like me, here is the gist of it

```
abstract class AbstractParam

abstract class AbstractClass<T: AbstractParam> {
    abstract fun f(p: T)
}

class Param: AbstractParam()

class Class: AbstractClass<Param>() {
    override fun f(p: Param) {}
}
```